# I Need help to find what smd component is this?

Tags: power-electronics, identification, components, surface-mount, siemens

[image]

This component is found on an electronic board of a Siemens Simatic S7-400 device.
The printed nomenclature on the electronic board reads '6C F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly a common BC817-40 or similar https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BC817_SER.pdf